# Is there a way to delay submitting a form to perform some animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The form is supposed to slideup and a new div will be displayed in the place of the form. The problem here is as **submit** is pressed the animation stops and hence it loads the next page. Is there a way to delay the submitting of the form so that the animations can take place.

**HTML**

```
<form class=" login myform" action='' method="post" id='frmlogin' name='frmlogin' >
<p class="">
<label for="username" class="">Your email&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="email" class=" " name="login_email"
id="login_email" autocomplete="email" value="" size='35' />
</p>
<p class="">
<label for="password" class="">Password&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class=" " type="password" name="login_password" 
id="login_password" autocomplete="password" size='35'   />
</p>
<p class="form-row">

<button type="submit" class="hello" name="login" value="Log in">Log in</button>
<input type="button" class="hello  " value="LOGIN" style="color:white;background: #c19d56;border:2px double #c19d56;outline: #c19d56 solid 1px;outline-offset: 2px; padding: 15px;width: 200px;cursor: pointer;letter-spacing: .19em;">
</p>

<p class="">
<a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
</p>
</form>
<div class="row w-100 mydiv" style="display:none;background: #c19d56;height: 100px;border-radius: 10px;">
    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Congratulations you are logged in!!
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".hello").click(function(){       
    $(".myform").slideUp("slow");
    $(".mydiv").css({ display: 'block' }, "slow");
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method to stop the form from submitting and the [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event to submit it like this:

```
$(".hello").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".myform").slideUp("slow");
  $(".mydiv").css({display:'block'},"slow");

  $("form.myform").submit();
});
```

Comment: `$(".myform").slideUp("slow", function() {  $("form.myform").submit(); });`

Comment: Or you can run the submit event in the callback of the `slideUp()` method as shown by @freedomn-m in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change login button to:

```
<button type="button" class="hello" name="login" value="Log in">Log in</button>
```

and use following jQuery to submit form:

```
$('.hello').click(function() {
    var $form = $('.myform');
    $form.slideUp('slow', function() {
        $('.mydiv').animate({
            'display: 'block'
        }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
            $form.submit();
        });
    });
});
```